# How to create a non-system user when installing Postgresql 8.4 with Rails 3.2.1 on Ubuntu 10.04 VM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-postgresql

Today I tried to install Rails 3.2.1 with Postgresql 8.4 on my local Ubuntu 10.04 VM.  I basically followed the instructions from http://www.mcbsys.com/techblog/2011/10/set-up-postgresql-for-rails-3-1/ .  The only thing I had to do differently was change a line in pg_hba.conf to "local postgres myapp trust" since the default user postgres didn't have a password and I had to create a postgresql user called "login_name" that matched my Linux system login user name (let's call it "login_name" for the sake of this example), otherwise I could not use rake db:create to create the db.

My database.yml file looked like this:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: development_db
  pool: 5
  user: login_name
  password: some_random_password
```

**My question is why did I have to create a user name that matched my system login name to get this to work and is there a way around this?**  I Googled the heck out of this and really couldn't find a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at your PostgreSQL configuration, you'll find two related files there :

1. pg_hba.conf
2. pg_ident.conf

pg_hba controls the mechanism how to handle auth request, typically with an entry like this :

```
local   all         all                          ident
```

**ident** means, all local/unix-socket connections where done with the system user's identity.

If you have a "non-system" user, you need to create a map in pg_ident.conf for them :

```
# MAP    OS-Name    DB-Name
myusers  user       user
myusers  user       dbuser
```

Alter pg_hba.conf like this:

```
local    all      all      ident map=myusers
```

Authentication is very well documented in the config files and online in the [PostgreSQL Administration Guide](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-IDENT)

Answer (score 0):

The name you specify in `user:` is the name used to log in; you do not have to have that be the system user if you don't want.  The thing is, when the database is *initialized* its owner is (typically) set to the username who did the `db_init`, which can vary.  So the username of the host and the username in the database tend to be loosely coupled.

From a security standpoint, a best practices is to run `init_db` as the `postgres` user, and then explicitly `GRANT` permissions, or change the owner of the `template1` database (and password) to be the one you want your applications to use.  Databases (more accurately schemas) will use the settings of `template1` when they are created.

Practically speaking, on web-accessible servers, I like having a (system) username with limited access (little or no `sudo`) that has the *same name* as the database user.  Set a name and use it everywhere.  This makes it easier to copy databases, configure, and so on.  Otherwise you end up getting "role foo not found" errors.

Rails makes it super easy to get going in development and that's good.  It should not make it super-easy to create an insecure production environment :-)